# I am geting Notice: Undefined offset: 14 in C:\nn\htdocs\myfiles\PHPCode.php on line 18

Tags: php, undefined

I am trying to find a string in other string. I am not allowed to use any of str function. Therefore, I wrote this code! But it shows  `Undefined offset: 14 in C:\nn\htdocs\myfiles\PHPCode.php` on line 18. 
I do not know what's wrong with this line.

```
if ($arr1[$j] == $arr2[$index])
```

The full code

```
<?php
        $stringR = strtolower($_POST['name']);
        $first   = strtolower($_POST['First']);
        $k = 0;
        $index    =0;
        $firstfeq =0;   
        if (preg_match('/[0-9]/', $stringR)){
            echo "ERROR:The String has numbers"."<br>";
            exit;
        }
        if (( strlen($first) > 8 )){
            echo "ERROR: Number of char in each input should be less     than 8 char"."<br>";
            exit;
        }
        $arr1 =  str_split($stringR);
        $arr2 =  str_split($first);
        for ($j  = 0 ; $j <= sizeof($arr1) ; $j++) {
            if ($arr1[$j] == $arr2[$index]){
                if ($index <=  (sizeof ($arr2))){
                    $k = 1;
                    $index++;
                }else 
                {
                    $index = 0;
                    $k =0;  
                }
                if (($index == sizeof($arr2)) && ( $k == 1)) {
                    $firstfeq++;
                    $index =0;
                    $k = 0; 
                }

            }

        }
        echo "$first appears $firstfeq"."<br>"; 

?>
```

Comment: `$index` of 14 does not exist in the `$arr2` array... error says it all.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
for ($j  = 0 ; $j <= sizeof($arr1) ; $j++) {
```

to this:

```
for ($j  = 0 ; $j < sizeof($arr1) ; $j++) {
```

I bet $j is going 1 index above the total limit.

Answer (score 1):

Since Arrays are indexed from 0, you should replace this line

```
for ($j  = 0 ; $j <= sizeof($arr1) ; $j++) {
```

with

```
for ($j  = 0 ; $j < sizeof($arr1) ; $j++) {
```

and similarly

```
if ($index <=  (sizeof ($arr2))){
```

with

```
if ($index <  (sizeof ($arr2))){
```